# High memory consumption on idle Kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i´ve created a cluster on google cloud platform consisting of 3 g1-small instances and have not yet added any pod / service / etc. Still, when I log on to the Kubernetes UI, all three instances show a very high memory consumption of ~ 1.3 GB. What is this memory used for? Or is it a problem with the kubernetes ui?

[image]

Thanks,
Fabian

Answer (score 2):

kube-ui seems to be showing the total memory usage, as opposed to the memory working set. The former includes inactive pages which are not in use, so the memory would appear higher. To see the memory working set, you can try reaching other monitoring services such as monitoring-grafana (backed by heapster) or simply reach the cadvisor port on the node.

To reach cadvisor:
Run `kubectl proxy` and then open
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/nodes/NODENAME:4194/

Alternatively, you can deploy [kubedash](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubedash) as your UI.

Comment: Additionally, g1-small is pretty small, given that we have some amount of overhead required per node.